# Magento2: Guest checkout error - No such entity with cartId =

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, guest-checkout, adobe-commerce

I'm getting this error while guest checkout. Please let me know if anyone knows the solutions.

**No such entity with cartId = b9bjhi5wbeEs20PIP9WXxiBgF32gcpHY**

**Adobe Commerce ver. 2.4.4-p2**

[image]

Thank You.

Comment: This error come when cart id either converted to the successful order or assigned to some customer. Can you please add the exact steps when this was happening.

Comment: These are the steps
Add to cart >> check out (shipping step) >> checkout step (payment step) >> hit the place order button or apply the discount code.

Comment: If you can access the database, please verify the cartHash, and it appears that your order has been successfully placed. I suspect this issue occurred during the order placement stage rather than when applying discounts, and it's possible that a third-party module is impacting the checkout process, which is worth investigating.